# Fire Emblem Heroes weapon Mt stat not added to damage?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Every site I've found describes combat in FE Heroes to be Strength + Weapon Mt - Enemy's Defense(or resistance if magic attack). However in testing this I've found that the Weapon Mt is not included. For example:

Attacker: Strength 46, Weapon Mt 15

Defender: Resistance 25

Damage = 21

Shouldn't it be 36 damage if Weapon Mt is added? There were no skills or adjacency bonuses involved so that is not the reason. Am I missing some other factor?

**Edit:** It was a Green Tome user against another Green tome user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Attack stat already includes the weapon's Might

Unlike most Fire Emblem games, Heroes does not have dedicated Strength and/or Magic stats. Instead, it has a single Attack stat that covers both physical and magic damage. However, it also already includes the Might of your currently-equipped weapon. If you go into the Equip Skills menu and change a unit's currently-equipped weapon, you'll see their Attack stat also change accordingly (you don't need to confirm the weapon change, the stats will update immediately).

Therefore, when calculating damage, don't add your weapon's Might to your Attack stat, because it has already been added.